# how to use tensor datasets in a DNN using embedding and textvectorization layers with multi class classification?

Tags: python, tf.keras, tensorflow-datasets, kaggle, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use tensor datasets from tensorflow. Link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly I am trying to replicate the same models and mechanisms that I use when working with arrays. I know some of the advantage in performance by working with them, but I am having problem using appropriately in DNN models and multiclass classification.

```
#Data Loading
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import tensorflow as tf # layers of keras
df_tweets = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/cyberbullying-classification/cyberbullying_tweets.csv")


#Data Cleaning
#Checking Missing Values
def check_missing_values(col):
    counter = 0
    for element in col:
        if element == True:
            counter += 1
    return counter
    
df_tweets.isnull().apply(lambda x: check_missing_values(x))

#Checking Duplicates
def check_duplicated_values(x):
    return x.duplicated().sum()
    
df_tweets.apply(lambda x: check_duplicated_values(x))
df_tweets = df_tweets.drop_duplicates(subset=['tweet_text'])

#Data Transformation
#Balancing the Dataset
df_tweets = df_tweets.groupby(by="cyberbullying_type").sample(n=1000, random_state=1)

#Data Preprocessing
#I am going to create a list of tokens to be used in the DNN model. A term-document to be used as input into the model without stopwords. Furthermore, I will going to use tensorflow layers for the preprocessing together with spacy library.

#Spacy and Tensorflow
import spacy
import re

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# to be used in the without stopwords version
all_stopwords = nlp.Defaults.stop_words 

# Remove URLs
def remove_urls(text):
    text = re.sub(r"\S*https?:\S*", "", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    return text

#Converting Dataframes to Keras Dataset
#We are changing some parameters to simulate different escenaries.

cyberbullying_types = set(df_tweets['cyberbullying_type'].unique())

def prepare_tokenize_without_stopwords(cell):
    if isinstance(cell.numpy(),bytes):
        cell = bytes.decode(cell.numpy())
    else:
        cell = (cell.numpy().tostring()).decode('unicode_escape')
            
    nlp_text = nlp(cell)
    tokens = [remove_urls(token.text).lower() for token in nlp_text if token.text.isalnum() and not token.text in all_stopwords]
    converting_to_tensor = " ".join(tokens)
    # reconverting it to tensor
    return converting_to_tensor
    
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_tweets.tweet_text,df_tweets.cyberbullying_type)) 
# ds is the tensor dataset

def tf_tokenize_without_stopwords(value,label):
    result =  tf.py_function(prepare_tokenize_without_stopwords, inp=[value], Tout=tf.string)
    # to get the same shape, and avoid an unknown shape
    result.set_shape(value.get_shape())
    return result, label

ds = ds.map(lambda x, y : tf_tokenize_without_stopwords(x, y)) 

#Modelling
regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(0, 0.001)
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=3000,output_mode='tf_idf',pad_to_max_tokens=True) # tf_idf
# Make a text-only dataset (no labels) and call adapt to build the vocabulary.
text_ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds,batch_size=None, steps=None)
classes_len = 6
vocab_size = len(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()) # 3000

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(vectorize_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,output_dim=20))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes_len, kernel_regularizer=regularizer))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Softmax())

model.summary()                                           
                                                               
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                 loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
epoch = 15
batch = 30
history = model.fit(ds, epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch)
```

The error that I am getting is the next:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpd2U.png)

The dataset is from kaggle datasets and it looked originally like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th86Q.png)

The result that I am getting is an error when using tensor datasets. It is different to the arrays version which worked fine. I meaned it work fine when using arrays.